# What is the difference of adding reference directly and adding package by Nuget

Tags: c#, powershell, nuget

I want to reference the `system.management.automation.dll` from `Powershll5.0` in my C# project, what is the difference between add reference manually and adding by Nuget package?
And how can I guarantee that the machine that my application runs on has this assembly in the reference path? Even I include this dll in my application installer, this dll is not in the reference path, can the machine automatically locates the dll?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference of adding reference directly and adding package
>   by Nuget

NuGet essentially does not differ from manually adding references, and ultimately adds references to the project. It is a tool that automatically adds assemblies to us and manages them, effectively improving the efficiency of our development projects.

For more details, you can check the document about nuget:

> Put simply, a NuGet package is a single ZIP file with the .nupkg
>   extension that contains compiled code (DLLs), other files related to
>   that code, and a descriptive manifest that includes information like
>   the package's version number. Developers with a code to share create
>   packages and publish them to a public or private host. **Package
>   consumers obtain those packages from suitable hosts, add them to their
>   projects, and then call a package's functionality in their project
>   code. NuGet itself then handles all of the intermediate details.**
>
> Because NuGet supports private hosts alongside the public nuget.org
>   host, you can use NuGet packages to share code that's exclusive to an
>   organization or a workgroup. You can also use NuGet packages as a
>   convenient way to factor your own code for use in nothing but your own
>   projects. In short, a NuGet package is a shareable unit of code, but
>   does not require nor imply any particular means of sharing.
>
> Is it just that .nupkg can contain a whole bunch of other things aside
>   from a .dll (e.g. documentation)?

Yes, NuGet package could include specifying files in the package.

> Why would I use one or the other?

Nuget provides several additional benefits:

- It automatically configures your projects by adding references to the necessary assemblies, creating and adding project files (e.g. configuration), etc.
- It provides package updates.
- It does all of this very conveniently.
- I'm sure that once you use it, you'll realize that it has many benefits.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in dll-reference point of view. NuGet-references ends up to normal dll-references to your assembly. NuGet is a tool that automatically adds assemblies to us and manages them. You can also make that management by hand (by adding references by hand).

As [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/what-is-nuget) states, NuGet-package is broader concept than single dll-refence. There can be multiple dll's, other files and metadata inside single NuGet-package.

> Put simply, a NuGet package is a single ZIP file with the .nupkg
>   extension that contains compiled code (DLLs), other files related to
>   that code, and a descriptive manifest that includes information like
>   the package's version number. Developers with code to share create
>   packages and publish them to a public or private host. Package
>   consumers obtain those packages from suitable hosts, add them to their
>   projects, and then call a package's functionality in their project
>   code. NuGet itself then handles all of the intermediate details.

Use NuGet whenever possible.

Comment: when I use the NuGet it will help me add assemblies, do I also need to copy these assemblies to the machine along with the exe to the server that it runs on?

Comment: Yes. Referenced assemblies are needed when running application

Comment: How the exe locates the dll? They are not in the reference path

Comment: Typically referenced assemblies need to be in same directory than .exe

Comment: I have tried the exe can run without copying `System.management.automation.dll`, is it because that this dll is installed when install Windows SDK? so I do need to copy it along with the exe ?

Answer (score 0):

I no going to provide definition answer but to answer your last question

> And how can I guarantee that the machine that my application runs on has this assembly in the reference path? Even I include this dll in my application installer, this dll is not in the reference path, can the machine automatically locates the dll?

From my understanding, adding dll from Nuget is equivalent to 
download dll into `packages` and set reference path in `.csproj`. But adding dll manually is not guarantee that the dll is there.

It is better to have reference path in `.csproj` so that visual studio will take these dll packages as consideration into your build output folder. To conclude, if the packages has Nuget version, use it; else, manually add it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is more a **build-engineering** then **powershell** specific.
You should use a package management tool in any language to put outside of your project all external or 3rd party dependencies. (nuget, artifactory, nexus, gradle chache etc)

This way:

- your project will work the same on any environment and you don't need to document what needs to be put in your environment and where to make it work :)
- you will have a mean to control in a single place everything that comes as a build or runtime dependency.
- you will have total control on the versions. Dependencies change in time and you might want to stick with an older version.
- you can use the same dependency in multiple places without storing it 1000 times and be sure it is the same package in use everywhere (single source of truth)

As a good practice, even the simplest script should have a version and a manifest file that mentions the dependency and the version. Just ask yourself what would you need to know after 4 years if you want to use that project again.